# function jumpTo() in owlCarousel 2.0 doesn't exist?

Tags: owl-carousel

I'm asking if someone has found a solution to this problem on the beta of owlCarousel 2.0?
The 1.0 version of the plugin can do it so I don't know why they doesn't integrate this to the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just renamed to `to`. You can use it in the following ways:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel('to', position)
$('.owl-carousel').trigger('to.owl.carousel', [position])
$('.owl-carousel').data('owl.carousel').to(position)
```